# How to display the values from an app.config file

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a loop that increments and display the increment number when a mouse hovers over a button. the values for each button is stored in an `app.config` file.how do i use the incremented value to show the correct value name?

Current code

```
public void Controls()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= Applications; i++)
    {
        string iconPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Application"+i+"_Icon"];
        Button button = new Button();

        this.Controls.Add(button);
        top += button.Height+25;
        button.Tag = i;
        button.MouseHover += Button_MouseHover;
        button.MouseLeave += Button_MouseLeave;
        button.Visible = true;

        button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
   }
```

`app.config`:

```
 <appSettings>
  <add key="Applications" value="3" />

  <add key="Catergory" value="1"/>
  <add key="Application1_Name" value="word"/>
  <add key="Application1_Executable_Name" value="word.exe"/>
  <add key="Application1_AutoClose" value="true"/>
  <add key="Application1_Icon" value="C:\pictures\images.png"/>

   <add key="Catergory" value="1"/>
  <add key="Application2_Name" value="Paint"/>
  <add key="Application2_Executable_Path" value="C:\Windows\System32\"/>
  <add key="Application2_AutoClose" value="true"/>
  <add key="Application2_Icon" value="C:\pictures\images.png"/>


  <add key="Catergory" value="1"/>
  <add key="Application3_Name" value="notepad"/>
  <add key="Application3_Executable_Path" value="C:\Windows\"/>
  <add key="Application3_AutoClose" value="true"/>
  <add key="Application3_Icon" value="C:\pictures\images.png"/>

</appSettings>
```

Currently when I hover over a button it shows me the values 1,2,3 but I want it show me Notepad, Word, Paint.

What I tried

```
public void Controls()
{
        for (int i = 1; i <= Applications; i++)
        {
            NameValueCollection sAll;
            sAll = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

            Button button = new Button();

            this.Controls.Add(button);
            top += button.Height+25;
            button.Tag = i;

            foreach(string s in sAll.AllKeys)
            {
                button.Text = s + i ;
            }
        }
}
```

What this does is that it shows me 1,2,3 and paint is displayed for everything.

Comment: All of your keys is named Application1_Name? Shouldn't they be Application1_Name, Application2_Name and Application3_Name

Comment: yes sorry it is like that,didnt notice i didnt change it,my apologizes.i have updated my question

Comment: What exactly you want to print on button - "Application1_Name" OR "Notepad"?

Comment: it must show notepad

Comment: Your app.config is wrong
you have so many keys can you please let me know that what you want to display at the button?

Comment: see each button when its clicked it opens an application,which works,what i want to do is add the name to each application.like each button must show its respective name,so the next time when i want to add more buttons to the form i will just enter those keys into the app config file.

Comment: That means you need the applicatioName at the button like Notepad,Paint.
Am i right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need the value of the key so you you should do something like following inside your loop.

And you doesn't need the foreach loop.

Just use as following it will help you

As you are using the foreach loop, which is not required at all.

So remove it as because it will increase the time-complexity.

In case you have multiple Keys in your App.config but you want to get some of them then you should have a specified format for the Application_Name like:

- application_name1
- application_name2
- application_name3
- application_name4

then do the following in your code then you can add as many buttons you want only by adding the key to the config file.

```
public void Controls()
    {
            for (int i = 1; i <= Applications; i++)
            {
                NameValueCollection sAll;
                sAll = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

                Button button = new Button();

                this.Controls.Add(button);
                top += button.Height+25;
                button.Tag = i;
                button.Text = sAll["application_name"+i] ;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `s` variable is actually the `appSetting` key. You need to further pass this `Key` to get the respective `appSetting` value to `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`.

```
        NameValueCollection sAll;
        sAll = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

        foreach (string s in sAll.AllKeys)
        {
            var applicationNamevalue = sAll [s];//Just for demonstration, should combine these statements.
            button.Text = applicationNamevalue + i; //and set it as button text.
        }
```

And yes a good suggestion by @Shivang, if you really do not care about what the value of the key, so can directly use the index to get configuration value.

Comment: as you already have all the key along with value in sAll so you shouldn't instantiate it again. in the loop.

Comment: @SHIVANGRANA - Thanks for the hint. Corrected :)

Comment: hi its still showing me Application3_Name for all.i have updated my config file so it shows you the whole view

Comment: Check out my answer that will help you @doe

Comment: @doe - Thats weird :(. It is too simple to not work. I have tested it, working for me, may be some more details could help.

Comment: i have updated my app config file,it shows all the records

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"];
```

So, for your case, use value from NameValueCollection, not the key

```
    button.Text = sAll[s] + i ;
```

Comment: i tried that and it doesnt display nothing, but how does it know that the value matchs the increments

Comment: Do not set key as text, set value as text. See my updated answer

Comment: there is no need of another foreach loop.

Comment: I did not use another foreach loop. I just modify his loop. Can't see that? @SHIVANGRANA

Comment: Bro i am saying about this loop only.
As his for loop for the application will be suffice to get the values.

Comment: @EmdadulSawon You can check my answer for reference that's what i was trying to say...

Comment: Loop is not part of the question. He wanted to know how to read from app.config @SHIVANGRANA

Comment: @EmdadulSawon yep you are right, but the provided solution is good if it is optimized.

Answer (score 1):

In your app config file, a better and more clean approach would be to add the application names in a config section like this

```
<configSections>
    <section name="ApplicationList" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
<configSections>
```

Then add each application name connected to the config section

```
<ApplicationList>
    <add key="1" value="Notepad"/>
    <add key="2" value="Word"/>
    <add key="3" value="Paint"/>
</ApplicationList>
```

It can then be used like this

```
var applications = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ApplicationList") as NameValueCollection;
for (int i = 0; i < applications.Count; i++)
{
   var applicationName = applications[i].ToString() ;
}
```

And over to the logic in the Controls function: If the totalApplication gets you all current applications then why do you loop over each name in the sAll.AllKeys?

Shouldn't the loop be coded like this

```
public void Controls()
  {
       var applications = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ApplicationList") as NameValueCollection;
        for (int i = 0; i < applications.Count; i++)
        {
            var button = new Button();

            this.Controls.Add(button);
            top += button.Height+25;
            button.Tag = i;
            button.Text = applications[i].ToString();
        }
   }
```